# python 3.5 find_all statement

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Need some help here.  I am trying to just print out the text "Whirlpool® 18 cu.Ft. Top Freezer Refrigerator  - WRT148FZDB" but haven't figure out the correct structure in the find_all statement.  I am currently calling the find_all as the code below but I know that is wrong.

```
g6_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product_name"})
```

The following code is what I am trying to scrape the information out of.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
<div class="product_info">

        <div id="product_name_7267017" class="product_name">

            <a aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="CatalogEntryViewDetailsLink_7267017" href="http://www.sears.ca/product/whirlpool-18-cuft-top-freezer-refrigerator-wrt148fzdb/646-000153197-WRT148FZDB"><span itemprop="name">Whirlpool® 18 cu.Ft. Top Freezer Refrigerator  - WRT148FZDB</span></a>
            <input type="hidden" id="ProductInfoName_7267017" value="Whirlpool® 18 cu.Ft. Top Freezer Refrigerator  - WRT148FZDB">
        </div>
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? What happens when you try this?

Comment: Nitpicking, but that's a method (a type of function), not a statement.

Comment: Can you give a link to the page you are getting the html from? I know it's somewhere on sears but what page exactly

Comment: Here is the page I am trying to scrape  http://www.sears.ca/catalog/appliances-fridges-freezers-refrigerators-top-freezer-en-wp-836#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:100&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the text from the anchor tags inside the divs, you can use a css selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.sears.ca/catalog/appliances-fridges-freezers-refrigerators-top-freezer-en-wp-836#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:100&").text)


for a in soup.select("div.product_name a"):
    print(a.text)
```

Comment: thanks, that woks.  just now I have to figure out the formatting with another method